# what is the idea and use of when(mock.method()).thenReturn(someValue) in mockito

Tags: java, mockito, mockmvc

In many tutorials found examples with following similar statement
**when(mock.method()).thenReturn(someValue);**

Can anyone please trigger out why this is used?? Is that invoking the method and expecting the result as such given inside thenReturn() statement?? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, basically. The names are quite self explanatory -- which is one of the strong points of mockito when compared to other similar frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mocking, you're trying to *simulate an object implementation*, and the `when` call helps you *describe the return values that the simulated object should have*. Because the documentation is pretty self-explanatory, I'll assume for the rest of the answer that you're looking for how Mockito is supposed to work and how `when` helps you set up your mocks.

Let's make an interface to work with:

```
interface Foo {
  int bar();
}
```

Presumably there is some implementor of `Foo.bar` out there, but maybe that implementation is hard to use in tests: It may use file storage, a network service, or some sort of random value. (Or, maybe, you haven't written the real implementation yet.) Now, you've written a class called `YourClass` that depends on a `Foo` instance, but you can't use a real one in your tests for any of the above reasons. What do you do?

One way is to write a very small implementation in your test:

```
Foo fakeFoo = new Foo() {
  @Override public int bar() { return 42; }
};
YourClass yourClass = new YourClass(fakeFoo);
```

Now you've written `fakeFoo` to have a predictable and easy-to-understand return value. This works for something this small, but it doesn't scale: What if Foo has a dozen methods? What if rather than returning 42 every time, you want to return a different predictable value each time? What if you want to check later on whether `bar` was called? Mockito helps you do all that by switching the syntax:

```
Foo mockFoo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
when(mockFoo.bar()).thenReturn(42);        // <- the statement you're asking about
YourClass yourClass = new YourClass(mockFoo);
```

Now, using the `when` statement, you're telling the *mock* Foo you've created what to return, which is just like the *fake* Foo implementation you wrote above for the same reasons. From there, you can write more `when` statements, or give your `thenReturn` more values to return in sequence, or use `verify` to check whether calls have been made. Above all, remember: You're not using `when` or making a mock of the class you're testing; you're mocking the classes *that collaborate with* the class you're testing.